# Syncs of RDBMS to Redis

Tags: caching, redis, data-synchronization

I have RDS that serves as the source of truth. A challenge that I have is to have this database partially synced to Redis to make it available for a server app to use. This would be a one way sync always going in one direction, but I can't wrap my head around what tools do I use to make these syncs happen preferably in an optimized way. In other words, rather than loading the entire data set it would be great if deltas are synced only.

I hope someone can give some insight on how this can be done.
Thank you!

Comment: You can only update Redis when mysql data changed not the entire table.

Answer (score 6):

Most RDBMS provide a way to subscribe to the transaction allowing you to put in place a "change data capture" event streams.

In this case you can subscribe to the databases events, and put the change or updated record inside Redis.

You can for example use [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) to capture the event, as you can see Debezium community has connectors for various datasources.

```
---------          ------------         --------- 
| RDBMS |========>>| Debezium | ======> | Redis |
---------          ------------         ---------
```

This [demonstration](https://github.com/tgrall/redis-microservices-demo) (mostly Java) shows this (a little richer since it is using Redis Streams and an intermediate state), the event is capture by this [method](https://github.com/tgrall/redis-microservices-demo/blob/18ae54e17adad1e4edbfaa1cdd08df3f69c64301/db-to-streams-service/src/main/java/io/redis/demos/services/db/events/streams/listener/CDCEventListener.java#L87) so capture Insert/Update/Delete in MySQL and sending the information to Redis.

Another option, that does not match you need but interesting, is to do a "write behind" Cache. In this case you update the Cache in Redis and Redis push the update in RDBMS using [Gears](http://redisgears.io/).

You can find more information about this "write behind" with Redis Gears in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync).

```
---------          ---------         --------- 
| Redis |========>>| Gears | ======> | RDBMS |
---------          ---------         ---------
```